# What all can be published as python package?

Tags: python, pip

I have sample python script to do some activity in AWS cloud can i publish that as a package in pypi,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything that can be packaged can be published; the PyPI is there to share your Python code with the community.

Just follow the [PyPI tutorial](http://wiki.python.org/moin/CheeseShopTutorial) and make sure your package follows the guidelines.